# Check current date java

Tags: java, date

From java class [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) docs:

> before(Date when) Tests if this date is before the specified date.

When I use this method to test whether selected date is equal to today, I get `wrong` output message.

```
public class JavaApplication28 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, ParseException {

        Date date1;
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String statusDT ="2018-04-08";
        date1 = formatter.parse(statusDT);
        if (date1.equals(new Date())) {
            System.out.println("today");
        } else if (date1.before(new Date())) {
            System.out.println("wrong");
        }
    }
}
```

This is date1, which is today date

```
Sun Apr 08 00:00:00 MYT 2018
```

The equal method look not functiong as well

> equals(Object obj) Compares two dates for equality.

Comment: can you show us the full code please, so we can test it?

Comment: it would be really useful what `statusDT` is

Comment: @YCF_L post edited

Comment: @leoderprofi please check

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The given date `date1` represent today *but* with midnight time : `Sun Apr 08 00:00:00 MYT 2018`
- the date used for comparison `new Date()` represents also today *but* the actual time (about 15h10) : `Sun Apr 08 15:10:00 MYT 2018`

So `date1` if before actual `Date()` and it goes in the good `if` section

---

As the `Java8` introduce a new Date API, it's easier to use in most case :

- `LocalDateTime` which holds `Date` (day/month/year) and `Time` (sec/min/hour)
- `LocalDate` which holds the `Date` part and can be given from a `LocalDateTime.toLocalDate()`
- `LocalTime` which holds the `Time` part and can be given from a `LocalDateTime.toLocalTime()`

So if you don't matter of the time, and just want to check the *day/month/year* you can use only the `LocalDate` part from the `LocalDateTime` :

```
if (date1.toLocalDate().equals(LocalDate.now())) {
    System.out.println("today");                              //< ---
} else if (date1.toLocalDate().isBefore(LocalDate.now())) {
    System.out.println("before now");
} else if (date1.toLocalDate().isAfter(LocalDate.now())) {
    System.out.println("after now");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
long l1 = date1.getTime();
long l2 = (new Date()).getTime();
```

**Output**

```
1523142000000
1523192849177
```

The doc said :

> Compares two dates for equality. The result is true if and only if the
>   argument is not null and is a Date object that represents **the same
>   point in time, to the millisecond**, as this object. Thus, two Date
>   objects are equal if and only if the **getTime method returns the same
>   long value for both**.

***Your get wrong because you thing that equal compare only the date part, but NO, it also compare the time part***

---

### Another Solution

Because you are using Java 8 why not using `java.time` instead like this :

```
String statusDT = "2018-04-08";
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(statusDT, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));

if (date.isEqual(LocalDate.now())) {
    System.out.println("today");
} else if (date.isBefore(LocalDate.now())) {
    System.out.println("before");
} else {
    System.out.println("after");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Class `java.util.Date` contains both a date and a time-of-day - as can be seen in the output of your program. The `Date` you obtain by parsing the `String` has no time-of-day, only a date. In other words, its time-of-day is 00:00 (i.e. midnight). Hence the two `Date`s are not equeal.

And by the way, the link you provided for the *javadoc* of the `Date` class is the Java 8 documentation. If this means you are using Java 8, then there is a new Date-Time API. There is a tutorial at
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html

Comment: Is this an answer ?

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?